# getting user input from a form in backend (rails 4) that uses ajax 'get' call when search button is pressed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, react-rails

So, I have a React-Component (search_alerts.es6.jsx) that looks like this

```
class SearchAlerts extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
console.log(this.props);

this.state = {
  alertsArray: this.props.alerts,
  zipCode: null,
  bloodReq: null,
  minCompensation: null,
  maxCompensation: null,
  requiredTime: null,
  location: null,
  bloodType: null,
  keyWord: null
}

console.log(this.state.alertsArray);
}
........
```

and the ajax call that is responsible to call the get method looks like this

```
  $.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify(stringit),
    type: "GET",
    url: `/findalerts/`,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("Ajax Passed ");
      console.log(data);

      this.setState({
        alertsArray: data
      });

    }.bind(this),
    error: function(data) {
      console.log("Ajax failed: ");
      console.log(data);
    }.bind(this)
  });
```

in my routes.rb, I'm doing this

```
get '/findalerts', to: 'alerts#index' #Search Alerts
```

and in my alerts_controller

```
def index
@alerts = Alert.search(params[:keyword])
end
```

for the search, I'm doing this in alert.rb

```
def self.search(search)


    @alerts  = Alert.where("ZipCode LIKE :search ", search: "%#{search}%")
    @alerts += Alert.where("compensation LIKE :search ", search: "%#{search}%")

    @alerts += User.search(search)

end
```

Now if I pass the query in the url,like this,

```
http://localhost:3000/findalerts?keyword=117
```

it is returning for example all the alerts that has the zipcode starts from 117 as json, and the react component is fetching it and displaying it properly.
My question is, how to get the search working when user types the keyword in the search form? I've tried other examples from stack overflow,it didn't work, I know I'm missing something, but don't know what. Thanks!

Comment: are you firing the event on keydown? basically when the user is typing? Or am I missing your question?

Comment: <button  type="submit" onClick={this.updateSearch.bind(this)}>Search Button</button>

Comment: in update search function it's using stringit              
   
      let stringit = {"alerts": {
            zipCode: zipCode,
            bloodRequired: bloodReq,
            minCompensation: minCompensation,
            maxCompensation: maxCompensation,
            requiredTime: time,
            location: location,
            bloodType: bloodtype,
            keyWord: keyWord
      }};